# RegEx in ColdFusion either one digit or a specific word

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using Reverse() to reverse the string, this is handy because I can have [1] at the ones place, [2] at tens, [3] at hundreds.

```
<cfset Mileage = "123456" />
<!--- I also want <cfset Mileage = "EXEMPT" /> to be able to work. --->
<cfset MileageR = Reverse(Mileage) />
<cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",MileageR) />
<cfdump var="#MilArray#" />
```

Then I call each array (each number) using `#MilArray[1]#` and so on. Is there a way I can change the `\d` to accept either `\d` or the word `EXEMPT`?

Well It would still need to look like this: 
Array:
[1] T
[2] P
[3] M
[4] E
[5] X
[6] E

Or be able to be a number still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d|EXEMPT
```

Try this.Use `OR` operator `|`

Comment: @Vicki try `\d|E|X|E|M|P|T`